# JQ query on JSON file

Tags: bash, jq

I am having below code in JSON file.

```
{
  "comment": {
    "vm-updates": [],
    "site-ops-updates": [
      {
        "comment": {
          "message": "You can start maintenance on this resource"
        },
        "hw-name": "Machine has got missing disks. "
      }
    ]
  },
  "object_name": "4QXH862",
  "has_problems": "yes",
  "tags": ""
}
```

I want to separate "hw-name" from this JSON file using jq. I've tried below combinations, but nothing worked.

```
cat jsonfile | jq -r '.comment[].hw-name'
cat json_file.json | jq -r '.comment[].site-ops-updates[].hw-name'
```

Appreciated help from StackOverflow!!!

Comment: Why the `[]`after `comment`? `comment` is not an array. `.comment.site-ops-updates[]....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
▶ cat jsonfile | jq -r '.comment."site-ops-updates"[]."hw-name"' 
Machine has got missing disks.
```

Or better still:

```
▶ jq -r '.comment."site-ops-updates"[]."hw-name"' jsonfile    
Machine has got missing disks.
```

From the [docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/):

> If the key contains special characters, you need to surround it with double quotes like this: `."foo$"`, or else `.["foo$"]`.